# Removing multiple parts of a file name using cut

Tags: linux, sed, rename, cut

I have a bunch of files named like so:

CI2_S1_20201120_S75_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
CI2_S2_20201120_S76_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
AV2_S2_20201120_S61_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz

and I want to rename the files to

CI2_S1_R1.fastq.gz
CI2_S2_R2.fastq.gz
AV2_S2_R2.fastq.gz

and delete the other parts in between. I have this loop that was shared with me but it does not change anything.

```
for file in 'ls *.fastq.gz'
do
mv $file 'echo $file|cut -f1,2,6 -d "_" | sed 's/$/.fastq.gz/''
done
```

From my understanding, the `cut -f1,2,6` keeps the parts I want and `-d "_"` is the separator.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It should work. Did you get any error or other type of message? One thing you can do is a "dry-run" test, put an `echo` before the `mv` command to see what is going to happen. `echo mv "$file" ...`. Sed isn't really needed, just append the suffix `\`echo $file|cut -f1,2,6 -d "_"\`.fastq.gz`

Comment: *for file in \`ls \*.fastq.gz\`* shall be replaced with *for file in ./\*.fastq.gz* and *mv "$file"* shall be quoted otherwise your script will break on whitespaces. *\`echo $file | cut | sed\`* will work when using (deprecated) `\`` backticks instead (wrong) `'` single quotes for command substitution (or even better *"$(echo $file | cut).fastq.gz"* in double quotes)